# Leer datos de Excel con Qt Creator

Tags: c++, excel, qt

me gustaría saber como podría leer los datos de un excel desde una aplicación de Qt. Lo he intentado con el siguiente código pero lee datos sin sentido.

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QStreamText>

int main(){
    QFile archivo("datos.xlsx");
    archivo.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream datos(&archivo);
    QString dato_actual;

    while(!datos.atEnd()){
       dato_actual = datos.readLine();
    }

    archivo.close();
}
```

El archivo Excel que quiero leer está formado por dos columnas, en la columna "A" hay datos de tipo Fecha (dd//mm/aaaa) y en la columna "B" hay números enteros.

Gracias!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para leer un fichero Excel tienes que tener en cuenta que te puedes encontrar dos formatos diferentes:

- formato nuevo (2007 en adelante).
- formato antiguo (hasta 2003).

El formato nuevo (extensión XLSX) es un fichero comprimido con varios XML en su interior (prueba a abrir un XLSX con un compresor). El formato antiguo, en cambio, es un formato binario.

Este detalle puede ser importante o no... no lo especificas en tu pregunta así que lo dejo anotado por si acaso.

Para leer un Excel desde Qt tienes varias opciones a tu alcance:

**A mano**

Si te curras la rutina para descomprimir el fichero XLSX y le dedicas un tiempo al formato verás que acceder a los datos que necesitas puede ser tan sencillo como leer un XML desde Qt (con DOM, a bajo nivel, ... como más te guste).

**ODBC**

Puedes usar el libro de excel como si de una base de datos se tratase. De esta forma leer información es tan sencillo (o complicado) como lanzar la consulta SQL pertinente.

Para poder usar ODBC tienes que tener instalado el motor de bases de datos de Access. Dadas las posibilidades que ofrece esta opción no me voy a explayar mucho más... en Internet hay multitud de ejemplos.

**Usar librerías de terceros**

Aparte de la ya comentada `libXL`, otra buena candidata es (ya que estás con Qt), [QtXlsx](https://github.com/VSRonin/QtXlsxWriter). Esta librería, al estar diseñada con Qt como base, se debería integrar bastante bien en tu proyecto.

Answer (score 2):

Primero, tu algoritmo te va a leer tu archivo xlsx como si fuera un archivo de texto escrito (*.txt).

Para que puedas leer el archivo xlsx necesitarás de la librería de lectura y escritura de Excel: `#include "libxl.h"` Lo puedes descargar en su web: http://libxl.com/